# How to add tabs into Tab Control at design time in XML file

Tags: android, tabs

i am planning to design my page in multiple tabs using one XML file or page
i have tried to add tabs at run time using .java file 
but i need to add tabs at design time so that i can design my page before run time compilation but i could not find a way to add tabs at design time into GUI page (XML activity) can anybody tell me how to add tabs at design time in XML file

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can not define tabs completely from xml layouts. You must have to use addTab from java code to add tabspec.

I think you better use Fragments and ViewPager to create tab like design as tab is deprecated a long time ago.